# How can I run large number of commands in cmd in java without running out of memory?

Tags: java, command-prompt, processbuilder

I am using ProcessBuilder to launch commands on cmd. I am using the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c",arg);
```

this is being run for large number of times(100-150) for different arg. The computer is running out of memory for obvious reasons. How do I overcome this issue and smoothly launch the commands.

I have used threadpool with 5 threads. Doesn't help.

Comment: Can you show us the code? And the `OutOfMemoryError` too? What do you see if you monitor the java process with `jvisualvm` ? Is it possible that the actual cmd processes eat up the memory of the OS?

Comment: I don't see any "obvious reasons" for `OutOfMemoryError` in your example. Is it possible that those external processes use OS memory?

Comment: Each process is taking almost 1.8MB of memory. And at least hundred of them are being launched simultaneously.

Comment: You have to wait for a process to stop before you launch another.